# Docker-CE or docker.io package

Tags: 16.04, virtualization, docker, lxd

In my laptop I work mostly with LXD to have containers for development and manage LXD containers in production (integrated with Ansible).

I have one requirement to use `docker/docker-compose` for deployment. I know that I can install `docker.io` package (that have the patches for LXC compatibility) but now, Docker promote the use of Docker-CE/Docker-EE. In this case will be Docker-CE.

Do this one have the patches from the `docker.io` package that come in Ubuntu? or in the future the Docker-CE engine will can be deployed from the Canonical repositories or a PPA?

Comment: Asked in LXD GitHub - https://github.com/lxc/lxd/issues/3349

Comment: A similar question with several answers on StackOverflow: [What is docker.io in relation to docker-ce and docker-ee (now called "Mirantis Kubernetes Engine")?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45023363/711006)

Answer (score 11):

I know this question is old, but I believe that docker upstream has released a version that supports this now, so I thought I would just put up an answer on here.  So, in Ubuntu, you really have 2 options as of 18.04 (and really these mostly work on 16.04 as well):

## docker upstream archive

Currently, docker upstream recommends a more involved [set of instructions installing from a custom archive](https://docs.docker.com/install/linux/docker-ce/ubuntu/), etc.  This can also meet your needs as long as you grab their 17.06 and newer.

## `docker.io` package

`sudo apt install docker.io`

This is versioned and updated by Canonical/Ubuntu community members quite regularly, but does tend to lag upstream a bit.  You can keep this package held just like your regular apt packages on ubuntu.  You can read more about the [SRU exception on the Ubuntu wiki](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DockerUpdates) to see the quality controls that go into this.  The version in Xenial and Bionic are on or approaching 17.03, but they do appear to contain the patch you need to run in LXD.

Edit note: https://github.com/docker/docker-snap - docker snap no longer recommended as of this update (25 Sep 2018).  If this changes in the future, feel free to edit this answer.

Comment: Very helpful - thank you! Note however that the [snap](https://snapcraft.io/docker) restricts you somewhat: *In order to use 'docker build', 'docker save' and 'docker load', you need to place your dockerfile within $HOME. All files that you want docker to access to must be within this path.*
Also note that currently  docker.io (version 17.12.1-0ubuntu1, from about 2018-02-27) is more up-to-date than the the snap ( https://snapcraft.io/docker,  version 17.06.2-ce, from about 2017-09-05).
The custom repo from docker has docker-ce version18.03.1-ce (2018-04-26)

Comment: I removed the snap reference for now as it's no longer suggested/recommended.

Comment: Interesting - who says snap is no longer recommended for docker?  Also, note it still says here that there are 3 options - might want to fix that too, or add snap back in and note it isn't recommended (with a cite).

Comment: @nealmcb updated answer with edit note.  I think the snap itself still works fine, but the maintainership is in question and is not receiving updates right now.