# i am unable to install couch DB in my ubuntu 18.04

Tags: apt, apache2, 18.04, couchdb

i am following the steps from this [link](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-couchdb-and-futon-on-ubuntu-14-04) to install couch DB in my system having ubuntu 18.04,but it says that release file is missing. steps work perfectly for my ubuntu 16.04

In https://apache.bintray.com/couchdb-deb/dists/ there is no dist for Ubuntu 18.04 LTS (Bionic Beaver). any help will be appreciated.

Thanks :)

Comment: This works now! Just not in the docs over at http://docs.couchdb.org/en/2.1.2/install/unix.html yet. Happy days.

Answer (score 2):

This doesn't exactly answer your question, but a simple option is to run couchDB in a docker container, and not as an installation. To do this simply install docker ([here's](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1030179/package-docker-ce-has-no-installation-candidate-in-18-04?rq=1) a question about how to do that), then once that is up and running run this command:

> sudo docker run -d -p 5984:5984 --name couchdb apache/couchdb:1.7.1

and an instance of couchdb will be running in a docker container. Go to http://127.0.0.1:5984/_utils/ to verify that its up.

Answer (score 2):

The couchdb team isn't building a binary package for Ubuntu 18.04 (Bionic Beaver) yet.

You can track the issue on github in order to get notified when the couchdb team makes progress on this:

https://github.com/apache/couchdb/issues/1314

If you have to run 18.04, then the only straightforward option is to build your own package from source.  Not a huge deal, but a fair number of dependencies, so not a trivial deal either.

http://docs.couchdb.org/en/2.1.1/install/unix.html#installation-from-source

**Update**

Support for bionic beaver has been added to the build process:
https://github.com/apache/couchdb/pull/1347

Docs aren't updated yet, but you should be able to use `bionic` in place of `{distribution}` (see the docs) and be all set.

http://docs.couchdb.org/en/latest/install/unix.html#installation-using-the-apache-couchdb-convenience-binary-packages

Comment: Sorry for getting your hopes up.  Bionic was/is showing up in the couchdb deb repo.  However if you follow the linked github ticket you will see that the actual packages aren't ready yet.  They were added to the build process but there is an "administrative holdup" blocking release.  So it seems the couchdb repo got updated before the packages were ready.   https://i.imgur.com/vgIasvR.png

Answer (score 2):

The following commands worked perfectly on my Ubuntu 20.04. It should work for 18.04 too:

**Enabling the Apache CouchDB package repository**

```
sudo apt update && sudo apt install -y curl apt-transport-https gnupg
 
curl https://couchdb.apache.org/repo/keys.asc | gpg --dearmor | sudo
tee /usr/share/keyrings/couchdb-archive-keyring.gpg >/dev/null 2>&1
 
source /etc/os-release

echo "deb [signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/couchdb-archive-keyring.gpg] https://apache.jfrog.io/artifactory/couchdb-deb/ ${VERSION_CODENAME} main" \
    | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/couchdb.list >/dev/null
```

**Installing the Apache CouchDB packages**

```
sudo apt update 
sudo apt install -y couchdb
```

Comment: This answer is the only one that worked for me!

Comment: @mahasamatman - please accept my answer if it worked.